# Microsoft Chart control and Reporting Services reports (SSRS)

Tags: .net, reporting-services, microsoft-chart-controls

I'm wondering whether anyone has been able to use the [Microsoft Chart control](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=130F7986-BF49-4FE5-9CA8-910AE6EA442C&displaylang=en) in SQL Server Reporting Service reports? Specifically the 2005 version...

Further to that, are the SSRS 2008 charts the same control (as the Chart control)? (i'm thinking that they are...)

Thanks heaps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't address whether these are the same controls as appear in SSRS 2008 (although it seems likely), but SSRS 2005 is based on .net v2.0, so would not support the version of the chart controls you have linked to in your question (which are for v3.5).

I assume you want this because the built-in charting in SSRS doesn't meet your needs?

Comment: good point about .net version 2...yeah, the charts offered in 2008 as well as the ms chart control really offer a lot more